# how to upload photos with other detail like username, email , mobie etc

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Here is my code to upload a Single Image. But i want to upload 3 images at a time.

How can i do it ?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process2.php" method="POST"> 
<table id="tbl1">

    <tr>
    <td>For Sale </td>
    <td colspan="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="id"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Type: </td>
    <td colspan="2">

    <select name="type" id="slct"><option>Residential</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>State: </td><td colspan="2">

    <select name="state" id="slct"><option>Punjab</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>City: </td><td colspan="2">

    <select name="city" id="slct"><option>Lahore</option></select></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>Location: </td><td colspan="2">
    <input name="location" placeholder="Enter Location Here" id="slct2" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>Bedrooms:</td><td colspan="2">

    <select name="bedroom"><option>1</option></select></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Land In: </td><td colspan="2">

    <select name="landtype" id="slct"><option>Kanal</option></select>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Land Area: </td><td colspan="2">
    <input name="landarea" placeholder="Enter area here" id="slct2" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Price: </td><td colspan="2">
    <input name="price" placeholder="Enter price here" id="slct2" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Photo</td>
    <td ><input type="file"  name="photo" id="file"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>User Details</td>
    <td colspan="2">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Name: </td><td colspan="2">
    <input name="name" placeholder="full name" id="slct2" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Mobile: </td><td colspan="2">
    <input name="mobile" placeholder="format 03001234567" id="slct2" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>E-mail: </td><td colspan="2">
    <input name="email" placeholder="Enter email Here" id="slct2" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Google "upload multiple files php" and you will find many results.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Start by declaring form elements for each of the three photos and its attributes.

Comment: i want to show you guys my php code but it is not posting here

Comment: this variable declares to save single photo now what i should edit    subir kumar                 $target = "uploadedimages/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

Answer (score 0):

add code in HTML

```
<td>Photo1</td><td ><input type="file"  name="photo1" id="file1"/></td>
<td>Photo2</td><td ><input type="file"  name="photo2" id="file2"/></td>
```

Add this code in your html and check selected images in your "process2.php" those are selected that store in your database.

When you insert this images in your database that time just do "img1,img2,img3" store this in your image colum...  This is the simplest way if your requirement is only 3 images then you can follow this.